# How to set dynamic page_size in DRF PageNumberPagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In class `PostByFilters`, I'm getting `limit` as a url parameter, and I want to assign the value into `page_size` in class `BasicSizePagination`. I tried to use global variable outside of the two classes, but it didn't work. Is there anyway reinitialize the `BasicSizePagination` in `PostByFilters` so that I can directly assign the value in `PostByFilters`?

```
class BasicSizePagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10

class PostByFilters(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    pagination_class = BasicSizePagination

    def get_queryset(self):

        limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit', None)
        ...

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create a new Pagination class from **`PageNumberPagination`** and override **`page_size_query_param`** attribute as below

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'size'  # items per page
```

Hence your URL will be, **`/api/foo/?size=10`** , this will return 10 items per page. If you not providing the **`size`** argument in the URL, DRF will use **`settings.PAGE_SIZE`**

Comment: Note that if size send is older than **max_page_size** will return the items number of **max_page_size**